# Improving a regex

Tags: regex

I am looking for alternate methods to get john from the provided example.
My expression works as is but was hoping for some examples of better methods.

Example: `john&home`

my regexp: `[a-z]{3,6}[^&home]`

Im matching any character of length 3-6 upto but not including `&home`

Every item i run the regexp on is in the same format. 3-6 characters followed by `&home`

I have looked at other posts but was hoping for a reply specific to my regexp.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Actually this regex isn't correct. With `[^&home]` you specify: all characters but `&home`. The result is that the regex is captured as `(joh)n` with `n` captured by `[^...]`.

Comment: I have been testing using http://www.rubular.com

Comment: simply `john`, or whichever name is before &home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most regex engines allow you to capture parts of a regex with capture groups. For instance:

```
^([A-Za-z]{3,6})&home$
```

The brackets here mean that you are interested in the part before the `&home`. The `^` and `$` mean that you want to match the **entire** string. Without it, `averylongname&homeofsomeone` will be matched as well.

Since you use *rubular*, I assume you use the Ruby regex engine. In that case you can for instance use:

```
full = "john&home"
name = full.match(/^([A-Za-z]{3,6})&home$/).captures
```

And `name` will in this case contain `john`.

Comment: `&home` not `@home` :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys, you stopped me using an incorrect expression that I thought was ok.